# como podria crear esta card desde javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap

Estoy trabajando con javascript, practicando de lo mas basico e ir avanzando poco a poco estoy usandp fetch para consultar la api de pokemones y realmente lo que quiero es que usando los backticks desde javascript poder crear las card o bien tener el molde e ir pintando cada pokemon, normalmente uso bootstrap y tengo en mi html mi contenedor con la clase de bootstrap que forma tres card una al lado de otra le he puedo mi id y desde js hago referencia a el, todo esta perfecto ya logro visualizar los nombres pero lo que pasa es que no me crea las card correctamente una se va hacia abajo de la otra en una fila, podria tener una guia de que estoy haciendo mal ya que lo he revisado pero no logro identificar el fallo.

```
const contenedorCarta = document.getElementById('cartaspoke');
fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/')
    .then(miRespuesta => {
        return miRespuesta.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        data.results.forEach(element => {
            contenedorCarta.innerHTML += ` 
            <div class="card-deck">
            <div class="card">
              <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">${element.name}</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>     
`  
        })
    })
<section class="container mt-5" id="cartaspoke">  
 </section>
```

Comment: ¿que versión de bootstrap estás usando?  La clase card-deck dejó de existir a partir de la versión 5 parece.

Comment: bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css esa es la version que estoy utilizando se debera a eso, porque segun yo he verificado el codigo y no encuentro falla y podria hacerlo con css desde cero pero queria probar con boostrap